# Форматированный вывод массива в скрипте bash

Tags: linux, bash

Каким образом в скрипте bash можно вывести массив на экран по n элементов в строку (n запрашивается у пользователя)?

Comment: Через for и \t попробуй, но возможно есть готовая программа для этого

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено. Конечно не такое красивое как хотелось бы, но все работает!

```
read n
tmp=1
for ((i=0; i < $size;i++))
do
    echo -n "${array[i]}    "

    if [ $n == $tmp ]; then
          let tmp=1
          echo
    else
          let tmp++
    fi
done
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

для выравнивания вывода по столбцам можно использовать [программу *column*](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/bsdmainutils/column.1.en.html):

```
$ echo -e "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7" | column -t
1  2  3
4  5  6
7
```

т.е., всё, что требуется — вывести ваш массив, добавив через требуемые промежутки символ перевода строки:

```
$ numcols=3
$ table=($(seq 1 7))
$ (for i in $(seq 1 ${#table[@]}); do \
   echo -n "${table[$i-1]} "; \
   if [ $((i%numcols)) -eq 0 ]; then echo; fi; \
  done; echo) | column -t
1  2  3
4  5  6
7
```

пришлось завернуть весь цикл в под-оболочку для того, чтобы после цикла вывести дополнительный перевод строки. иначе, при наличии в последней строке входных данных лишь одного значения, программа *column* не обрабатывает эту строку и жалуется:

> column: line too long

---

а вот если у вас встречаются элементы массива с пробелами внутри, то придётся немного усложнить процедуру, разделив элементы, например, символом табуляции:

```
$ table=(1 "2 и ещё что-нибудь" $(seq 3 7))
$ (for i in $(seq 1 ${#table[@]}); do \
   echo -n "${table[$i-1]}"; \
   if [ $((i%numcols)) -eq 0 ]; then echo; else echo -ne "\t"; fi; \
  done; echo) | column -s $'\t' -t
1  2 и ещё что-нибудь  3
4  5                   6
7
```